# How to create a list of symbols in online LaTex editor Overleaf?

Tags: table-of-contents, symbols

I would like to:
a) create a list of symbols;
b) which is listed on the table of contents.

I've tried the following code but the title "List of Symbols" does not appear on the table of contents, just a new line with the page number where the list of symbols is. On the page where the list of symbols is, the page is completely empty with just the title "List of Symbols".

```
\documentclass{article}

#several packages are stored here ...#

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listsymbolname}\listofsymbols
```

Comment: You might want to look up the `glossaries` package.

Comment: We'll need a lot more details to debug what you're trying to do.  A complete minimal example would help, not "several packages are stored here".  But for starters, how are you defining `\listsymbolname` and `\listofsymbols`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trial and error approaches, I think I got the answer by myself. I'm posting here the solution. This solutions applies for the document class **article**.

First, insert this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[final]{listofsymbols}
\renewcommand{\symheadingname}{List of Symbols}
```

Then, define your symbols. In this example, I have defined two symbols. Insert your definitions somewhere after ***\begin{document}***:

```
\opensymdef
\newsym[country]{country}{i}
\newsym[year]{timeyear}{t}
\closesymdef
```

Insert the following code after your definitions:

```
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\symheadingname}\listofsymbols
```

Use your definitions in the document. Here my (stupid) example:

```
\begin{equation} \label{eu_eqn}
\begin{split}
Lending_{it} = {\country} + {\timeyear}\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, having a table just like in a word processor does the same job without all the fuss. New symbol? Just add it to the table.